# JQuery Plugin Too Much Recursion on this.each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why am I getting too much recursion on a jQuery plugin `this.each` iteration?

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.selectableList = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.elem = $this.children('li').click(onClick);
    });
    function onClick() {
      //do something
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: version JQuery 1.3.2 btw

Comment: Hey Sam3k

I'm not sure what you mean by too much recursion. This code works fine for me.

Comment: As pointed by meosoft below, children() was causing a lot of recursion. You can tell by doing a simple console.log on each. using find() is working for me so far. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just:

```
$(this).find('li').click(onClick);
```

Instead of the 2 lines you have there, that should not produce too much recursion.